# Can't build boost libraries in 32bit with 64bit gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, 32-bit

I'm trying to build the Boost C++ libraries in 32bit form on a 64bit linux machine.
After running bootstrap.sh, I run:

```
./b2 address-model=32
```

All I get as output is a load of g++ output saying compilation terminated.
and a result of no libraries compiled, all skipped.
This is extremely frustrating for me as I cant find anyone else who is having the same issue. All answers seem to point to using the "address-model=32" option which doesn't work at all for me.

If i specify no options and just run:

```
./b2
```

Then all is well and the build is successful. But surly this builds 64bit libraries? Which is not what I want when my target is 32bit systems.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit and trying to build Boost 1.55.0.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you build 32-bit programs on the command-line using `g++ -m32` ?  You might need to install the `gcc-multilib` package

Answer (score 1):

1. setting customize build tool

   `echo -e "using gcc : : g++ : root=/usr/local/ <compileflags>-m32 <linkflags>-m32 ;">tools/build/v2/user-config.jam`
2. now you can build it with 32-bit program

   `./b2`